# Change instance of abstract class that use generics

Tags: c#

I am trying to replace derived instances in base class. It works for animals (simple usage of abstract class), but not with generics. The error is in `SomeMethod`. Is there any clean solution?

**EDIT:** With help of another interface it is truly doable. Code that is commented with [S] is solution for my original question.

```
public abstract class Animal
{
    public void Feed()
    {
    }
}

public class Tiger:Animal
{
}

public class Dog : Animal
{
}

public class Consumer
{
    public Tiger Tiger { get; set; }
    public Dog Dog { get; set; }

    public Animal FavoriteAnimal { get; set; }

    void SomeMethod()
    {
        // This is fine
        FavoriteAnimal = Tiger;
        FavoriteAnimal = Dog;
        FavoriteAnimal.Feed();

        //Also fine 
        int numberOfDogs = PlaceForDogs.CountAnimals();
        int numberOfTigers = PlaceForTigers.CountAnimals();

        //[S] This is doable now
        FavoritePlaceForAnimals = PlaceForDogs;//[S]  no more ERROR
        int numberOfAnimalsOnMyFavoritPlace = FavoritePlaceForAnimals.CountAnimals(); // No error, but I do not get here...
    }

    public PlaceForDogs PlaceForDogs { get; set; } = new PlaceForDogs();
    public PlaceForTigers PlaceForTigers { get; set; } = new PlaceForTigers();

    //public PlaceForAnimals<Animal> FavoritePlaceForAnimals { get; set; }
    //[S] favorite place is of type IPlaceForAnimals instead of PlaceForAnimals
    public IPlaceForAnimals FavoritePlaceForAnimals { get; set; }
}

//[S]new interface
public interface IPlaceForAnimals
{
    int CountAnimals();
}

//[S]abstract class implements the interface
public abstract class PlaceForAnimals<T>:IPlaceForAnimals  where T : Animal
{

    public List<T> Animals { get; set; }

    public int CountAnimals()
    {
        //special counting using properties from Animal class
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: "the error", what error? What is it?

Comment: I think the problem is caused by something called Variance. Google generic variance in C# as it's a bit too long winded to explain here. In short generic type arguments and parameters don't play normally with inheritance and polymorphism

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `PlaceForAnimals<Dog>` is not a `PlaceForAnimals<Animal`> (for purposes of assigning it that type), as it could not hold a tiger (while the original could).

The assignment is simply not legal without covariance. If you want to access certain methods you could have the base class implement a non-generic interface and make `FavoritePlaceForAnimals` be of that type.

Comment: In fact, a `PlaceForAnimals<Animal>` would typically make an acceptable `PlaceForAnimals<Dog>`, but this, too, is not allowed in C# without explicitly defining the collection type so that this works. For details, read up on covariand and contravariance. Eric Lippert has a great [series](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/10/16/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-one/) on the topic for C#. It's a little old, but it still covers most of how C# thinks of covariance and contravariance.

Answer (score 2):

The generic is wrapping a common set of functionality around a certain data type. Like `List<int>` functions the same as `List<string>`, it just gives you different data when you access it.

You could use a generic in the sense that your `PlaceForAnimals<T>` could have some defined behavior, but wrapped around a generic object like, say a `Dog`. But because it is just a wrapper around some functionality, it doesn't behave the same way as an inherited class like you have with your `Animal` superclass.

Inheritance lets you interchange data types, generics do not.